# Java Android Toast not showing after boolean declaration

Tags: java, android, toast

The toast that says `not reachable` is not showing up, but all the above are showing up, why does my code stop execution on that line?

```
if (msg_from.equals(MainActivity.PHONENUMBER)){
                    if (msgBody.startsWith("Your")){
                        //have seen this toast
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Yes!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         //have seen this toast



                        LocationManager imLoca = SysService.locationMan;

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Yes 2!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //have seen 



                        boolean gpsEnabled  = imLoca.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


                        Toast.makeText(context, "not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //but this does not show up,  and any thing after this line is not working;    
                        boolean netOn = imLoca.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (gpsEnabled){

                        //do some thing
                        }
                        else if (netOn){
                        //do some thing
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Failing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Possibly your app crashes because `imLoca` is null or for some other reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: does your code have the permissions to call the GPS stuff? you might be getting an exception on that call

Comment: instaed of showing toast use Log.i() method to get code running information log

Comment: Does your app crash? (NullPointerException for example)

Comment: @dube The permission are called properly, i have a class `SysService` which is working fine

Comment: try to add toast also in if, else if and then see what it shows.

Comment: @SoftCoder it does not show up

Comment: @laalto, Thanks, if that was an answer i would have marked it as Right one. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I copied this code into my test project and added a toast to the if and the else if for gpsEnabled and netOn.

It looks like the first if is the one that is getting executed as gpsEnabled is true.

Hope this helps, good luck.

```
if (gpsEnabled){
    //do some thing
    Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (netOn){
    //do some thing
    Toast.makeText(context, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Failing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: The problem was that `imLoca` was null

Answer (score -1):

Imloca returns null.Problem is this.

Comment: The problem was that `imLoca` was `null`, which is now fixed

Comment: this code would not compile in java and is a good sample why you always should use curly brackets.